# Server to process "n" requests from multiple clients concurrently in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, server, udp

I am writing a UDP Server in Java which handles packets from multiple clients & then processes it. What I have done is Server is listening for packets & as soon as it receives packet, it spawn a new thread to process it.
Below is the sample code :-

public void run()
    {

```
   try
   {
    serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5676);
    while(true)
    {
        byte[] receiveDataBuf = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveDataBuf,receiveDataBuf.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);    
        String sentence  = new String(receiveDataBuf,0,receivePacket.getLength());                  
        ReqHandler  rh= new ReqHandler (sentence);
        rh.start();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {   
    }
}
```

As client requests are received very frequently.Problem is  when I have checked CPU percentage , it is taking 20-30 % {sometimes above 30 %}. 
I think this might be because of ReqHandler  class which process data which is acting as while(true). 
How can i handle this ? or is there any other way to implement server which can process "n" requests concurrently {concurrently in database} .

Note :- ReqHandler is processing data in database.

Comment: Why not just use Netty? http://netty.io/

Comment: What you're doing is basically the v1.0 of how to write a server.  It isn't wrong, its the obvious way of doing things.  This is the expected problem with it.  Thread pooling (having threads waiting and ready to take data) is the next step up.

Comment: As I said in reply to @Peter Lawey's reply that even after using executor service , application is using high cpu percentage. so how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> it spawn a new thread to process it.

that is really expensive.  This is likely to be slower than not create a thread.

An alternative is to use a thread pool.

```
try {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5676);
    byte[] buf= new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

    while(serverSocket.isOpen()) {
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String sentence  = new String(buf, 0, buf.getLength(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        es.submit(() -> {
             try {
                new ReqHandler (sentence).run();
             } catch (Throwable t) {
                LOG.error("Unable to process " + sentence, t);
             }
         });
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOG.error(e); // don't ignore errors unless you know you can.
}
```

Note: your `ReqHandler` should `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`

Comment: I tried it but still CPU percentage goes high. But instead of writing es.submit(() -> { try { new ReqHandler (sentence).run(); } catch (Throwable t) { LOG.error("Unable to process " + sentence, t); } }); I have used es.submit(new ReqHandler(sentence));

Comment: @AKT16 In that case, I suggest using a CPU profile to determine what is using the most CPU. The the try/catch is to log any error which occur. If you don't do this any unhanded exceptions will be silently lost.

Comment: No such error occurs in the code. As I said this might be because of so many threads I am creating in order to process client requests  , which is acting as while(true) . Because If we run any program with while(true) without sleep , program will consume more percentage of CPU.So here  I am not able to get that how can I improve on this?

Comment: Instead of busy waiting you can wait on a blocking operation. The ExecutorService waits on a BlockingQueue to prevent busy waiting.